# MySQL procedure. LIKE pattern matching - cyrillic string

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, character-encoding

I'm having trouble with one MySQL procedure. The procedure itself works but only when I use latin characters. If I use cyrillic string it doesn't work. The table is in utf8_general_ci on the top of the page I have "SET NAMES 'utf8'". Any help regarding this post is appreciated. Below is my code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `selUsers`(IN usrNme VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN


SELECT *
    FROM users WHERE 1 
        AND (user_real_name LIKE CONCAT('%', usrNme, '%') OR user_company LIKE CONCAT('%', usrNme, '%') OR user_name LIKE CONCAT('%', usrNme, '%'))
    ORDER BY user_real_name ASC LIMIT 0, 15;

    END
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work, you should use `SET NAMES` after you open connection and select database, to tell mysql that client will use specific character set to send data. Check out [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) for details.
For your specific case, it should be

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Also, I would use utf8_unicode_ci instead of utf8_general_ci. It is true that utf8_unicode_ci is slower than utf8_general_ci, but you will get better comparison (more accurate)...utf8_general_ci is fine only for **Russian** and **Bulgarian** subset of Cyrillic. Extra letters used in **Belarusian**, **Macedonian**, **Serbian**, and **Ukrainian** are not sorted well...you should have that on mind if you will use some of the letters from those cyrilic alphabets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate that. I changed the procedure but no results when searching on Cyrillic. Below is the new code.                                                     DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE selUsers (IN usrNme VARCHAR(25))
    BEGIN

SET NAMES 'utf8';

SELECT user_id, user_real_name, user_company, user_name 
 FROM users WHERE 1 
        AND (user_real_name LIKE CONCAT('%', usrNme, '%') OR user_company LIKE CONCAT('%', usrNme, '%') OR user_name LIKE CONCAT('%', usrNme, '%'))
 ORDER BY user_real_name ASC LIMIT 0, 15;


    END //
 DELIMITER ;

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in your procedure, but how you call it from your code. After opening the connection, execute SET NAMES utf8 command, and check how it works then.

Comment: Prior calling the procedure I use SET NAMES utf8 and then mysql_query("CALL selUsers('".$que."')"); Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing encoding to utf8_unicode_ci...then, just check if you should really get some results.